# How to install OpenBSD 6.2 guest in XenServer 7?

Tags: xen, xenserver, openbsd

I'm trying to create new VM from vanilla OpenBSD 6.2 install CD on XenServer 7. I can't even boot install CD. Basically, i get this:

`Boot device: CD-Rom199MB medium detected
   - success.
   CR-ROM: E0
   Loading /6.2/I386/CDBOOT`

Then VM shuts itself down without any errors (tested also on 6.1 - same behavior).
Should i use some special CD image to install OpenBSD in XenServer? Or maybe some special kernel bootstring options?